# exceeded maximum execution time, google sheet, how to improve it?

Tags: function, loops, google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets

Good morning, everyone,

I come to see you because after having fought hard to make my google script work, on the execution page I see that my script works, however on my google sheet I have an error: "Exceeded maximum execution time". I've seen on the internet that for custom google script functions only leave 30 sec of execution, I'm not sure how to do that? add code to tweak this feature? I confess that I didn't understand the difference between a custom function and a google app script but I know that there is 6 minutes of execution time for scripts... here is an extract of my code:

```
// Standard functions to call the spreadsheet sheet and activesheet
function GetPipedriveDeals2() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

   //the way the url is build next step is to iterate between the end because api only allows a fixed number of calls (100) this way i can slowly fill the sheet.
  let url    = "https://laptop.pipedrive.com/v1/products:(id)?start=";
  let limit  = "&limit=500";
  //let filter = "&filter_id=64";
  let pipeline = 1; // put a pipeline id specific to your PipeDrive setup 
  let start  = 1;
  //let end  = start+50;
  let token  = "&api_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+start+limit+token); //
  let dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
  let dataSet = dataAll;
  //let prices = prices;
  //create array where the data should be put
  let rows = [], data;
  for (let i = 0; i < dataSet.data.length; i++) {
  data = dataSet.data[i];
    rows.push([data.id,
               GetPipedriveDeals4(data.id)
               ]);
  }

  Logger.log( 'function2' ,JSON.stringify(rows,null,8) );   // Log transformed data

  return rows;
}

// Standard functions to call the spreadsheet sheet and activesheet
function GetPipedriveDeals4(idNew) {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

   //the way the url is build next step is to iterate between the end because api only allows a fixed number of calls (100) this way i can slowly fill the sheet.
  let url    = "https://laptop.pipedrive.com/v1/products/"+idNew+"/deals:(id,d93b458adf4bf84fefb6dbce477fe77cdf9de675)?start=";
  let limit  = "&limit=500";
  //let filter = "&filter_id=64";
  let pipeline = 1; // put a pipeline id specific to your PipeDrive setup 
  let start  = 1;
  //let end  = start+50;
  let token  = "&api_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+start+limit+token); //
  let dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
  let dataSet = dataAll;
   //Logger.log(dataSet)
  //let prices = prices;
  //create array where the data should be put
  let rows = [], data;
  if(dataSet.data === null )return
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < dataSet.data.length; i++) {
      data = dataSet.data[i];
      let idNew = data.id; 
      rows.push([data.id, data['d93b458adf4bf84fefb6dbce477fe77cdf9de675']]);
    }
  
  Logger.log( 'function4', JSON.stringify(rows,null,2) );   // Log transformed data
  return rows;
  }
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT : --------------------------**FOR EACH LOOP**----------------------------

```
function getPipedriveDeals(start = 0,apiRequestLimit = 39) {
  console.log("start="+start);
  //Make the initial request to get the ids you need for the details.
  var idsListRequest = "https://laptop.pipedrive.com/v1/products:(id)?start=";
  var limit = "&limit=" + apiRequestLimit;
  var token = "&api_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(idsListRequest + start + limit + token);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data;
  
  //For every id in the response, construct a url (the detail url) and push to a list of requests
  var requests = [];
  console.log("data="+data);
  data.forEach(function(product) {
    var productDetailUrl = "https://laptop.pipedrive.com/v1/products/" + product.id + "/deals:(id,d93b458adf4bf84fefb6dbce477fe77cdf9de675)?start=";
    requests.push(productDetailUrl + start + limit + token)
  });
  
  //With the list of detail request urls, make one call to UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests)
  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
  return [responses,JSON.parse(responses[0].getContentText()).additional_data.pagination.more_items_in_collection];
  
}

function getAllDeals(){
  var allResponses = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<500; ){ 
    var deals = getPipedriveDeals(start=i);
    deals[0].forEach((response)=>{allResponses.push(response)});
  if(deals[1]){
    // If there are more items sleep for 1000 milliseconds
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    i+=39;
  }
  else{
    console.log("No more items in collection.");
    break;
  }
}
console.log("allResponses="+allResponses);
return allResponses;
}
```

About the weird behavior in the logs :
[image]

-------------------------------**EDIT Number2**----------------------------------

Until now when I executed `=getPipedriveDeals()`it return `False` (like I was saying in my comment)   and also when I try to remove `additional_data.pagination.more_items_in_collection` (Because it's not very usefull for me) I don't know why but the script won't work anymore, and I have some difficulties to select the data I want to return.

---

Comment: If to use `fetch` in the loop is the most reason of your issue, how about using `fetchAll`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)) But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So for example, in your script, what are the values of `ss`, `sheets` and `sheet`? Are not these used?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike and thank you for your quick response! 

the values "ss, sheets, sheet" are used to select the google sheet, I also noticed that they may not be necessary in my second function, it saved me about 8 seconds to remove them. I think you're right about the fetch, only I don't really know how to implement the FetchAll in the current state of things... according to the documentation it has to be attached to one or more requests, and I don't really know how to modify the code to do that without breaking everything I took a long time to write it and I got a little help...Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests) to save in quotas and likely a lot in script execution duration.

I have removed a few redundancies in your code to make this following example showing the use of `fetchAll` for your case.

### Example:

```js
function getPipedriveDeals(start = 0,apiRequestLimit = 50) {
  console.log("start="+start);
  //Make the initial request to get the ids you need for the details.
  var idsListRequest = "https://laptop.pipedrive.com/v1/products:(id)?start=";
  var limit = "&limit=" + apiRequestLimit;
  var token = "&api_token=xxxxxxxxxxx";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(idsListRequest + start + limit + token);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data;
  
  //For every id in the response, construct a url (the detail url) and push to a list of requests
  var requests = [];
  console.log("data="+data);
  data.forEach(function(product) {
    var productDetailUrl = "https://laptop.pipedrive.com/v1/products/" + product.id + "/deals:(id,d93b458adf4bf84fefb6dbce477fe77cdf9de675)?start=";
    requests.push(productDetailUrl + start + limit + token)
  });
  
  //With the list of detail request urls, make one call to UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests)
  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
  return [responses,JSON.parse(responses[0].getContentText()).additional_data.pagination.more_items_in_collection];
}
```

Now suppose you have a plan that limits the quota to 50 requests per 2 seconds.

You could make the limit of requests in the `fetchAll` call to 50, and introduce a [delay/sleep of (X) milliseconds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)) to initiate a second request, starting with id=50 like:

```js
function getAllDeals(){
  var allResponses = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<500; ){ 
    var deals = getPipedriveDeals(start=i);
    deals[0].forEach((response)=>{allResponses.push(response)});
  if(deals[1]){
    // If there are more items sleep for 1000 milliseconds
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    i+=50;
  }
  else{
    console.log("No more items in collection.");
    break;
  }
}
console.log("allResponses="+allResponses);
return allResponses;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ! It's look great but I have an error : ```{"success":false,"error":"request over limit","errorCode":429}``` not related directly to your script but due to the limitation of the API :https://pipedrive.readme.io/docs/core-api-concepts-rate-limiting I think I'll try to put a delay between the call if you have an idea you are welcome. Thanks again for your help it's fantastic

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Yeah, the 429 error is "Too many requests" so it is likely you are being limited. So you should take those limits into account. You are unlikely to have success implementing a delay because fetchAll will make all requests, and you have no possibility of adding a delay, but perhaps you can keep the number of simultaneous requests under the rate of your API account. Please have a look at [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hello @Aerials, thanks for your help but I still have 2 mains issue, the 429 error, I don't know how to solve it and I also noticed that this code was sending back empty object, I suppose I have to declare what object I want to return but, I dont know where to indicate this... (I'll edit my first post to put the image of GAS executions )... For the 429 error I thought to put Oauth in my script to increase my number of request but it's seem's to be very difficult, have you any other idea ? even if I have to rewrite a part of the function. Thanks again mate

Comment: @AlbanM for the function to return something, you just need to add a return statement. And I would suggest you find out your maximum daily requests quotas, and respect them. I have added a "apiRequestsLimit" parameter that you can use to limit the number of requests you are making to the pipedrive API. Even though you are making one call to `fetchAll` your token is being used as many as 500 times with the code as it was, clearly surpassing the rate limits. See updated answer.

Comment: In fact I found my request quotas, it's 80 calls every 2 seconds, if I use Oauth it's 360 calls every 2s. With the new code you gave me I have now an error ```12:40:04 Erreur TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at getPipedriveDeals(Copie de importNamesTypes:12:8)``` I suppose it's because the request return sometimes a null object ? Thanks

Comment: Oh thank youuuuuu, I didn't see your edit before I just test it. It's almost totally functional, there is just one or two things I don't really understand  :  How can I choose the data to Fetch ? (without taking all the data for exemple just take the Id of my second request) and in the stackdriver logs I have a weird behavior :  a lot of array that look like this : ``` [object Object] ```ll edit my first post and put a picture an how I integrate your code, really I dont know how to say thank you your help will save so many times to my colleagues they will love you !

Comment: In fact I see now that the function seem to work on Stackdriver, but it don't display on google sheet. (I use ``` =getAllDeals() ``` I even try to put the two functions in one and execute it but still blank) I think the function pushing the empty cells that we see on the log ?

Comment: Something I didn't notice yesterday, when I try to put ```=getPipedriveDeals()``` I get ```False``` in my google sheet, so I suppose It's the ```success: true``` That we see in the picture I put in my first post.  But I don't know why this return to me false I tried something like ```return AllResponses[0]``` but It didn't work as expected